# Gem dependencies versions meaning

Tags: ruby, version, rubygems

Gem dependency version can be specified with prefixes `=`, `<`, `>`, `<=`, `>=` and `~>`. I understand all except last one, what does `~>` mean?

Comment: An interesting fact: They call it the “spermy” version specifier. :)

Comment: This question is an exact duplicate of http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/3414337/ .

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `~>` operator means: match within the same version, depending on how specific you want it to be, here's some examples:

```
 Specification From  ... To (exclusive)
  ">= 3.0"      3.0   ... &infin;
  "~> 3.0"      3.0   ... 4.0
  "~> 3.0.0"    3.0.0 ... 3.1
  "~> 3.5"      3.5   ... 4.0
  "~> 3.5.0"    3.5.0 ... 3.6
```

[Source](http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Version.html)

Comment: Right source now - http://rubygems.rubyforge.org/rubygems-update/Gem/Version.html