# Dependency on different version of some gems

Tags: rubygems, chef-infra

I have been playing around with chef gem. And when I check it's dependencies, it turns out that it depends on multiple versions of some gems like json, chef-zero etc.

My question is why does a gem depends on multiple versions of same gem? I mean, shouldn't it be like that I install the latest version of chef-zero and it satisfy all the dependencies of chef? Further, is there any way I can make changes so that chef depends only on one version of chef-zero?

Answer (score 3):

Well that's the beauty of open source that anyone with great idea and good programming skill can contribute. But people don't start coding everything from scratch. Its an evolutionary process so a gem uses other available gems for their needs hence causing dependency.

A simple example is gems like 'PDFKit' or 'wicked_pdf'. Both are great gems for printing a html page to pdf.. but they use the same deependency i.e. 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'. As the later was already available it would have not been actually a good idea for the authors of these plugins to write that part of code. Its smarter this way.

So in-short you have to take care of dependencies yourself, but on a plus side almost every good gem clearly mentions their dependency status in their change log.

Comment: That sounds great. But what I want to know is why a gem is depending on multiple versions of same gem. I mean, wouldn't it be better if I had to install only one gem, instead of installing different versions?

Comment: have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132479/2-gems-need-different-versions-of-the-same-dependency , maybe it will help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's not exactly that. You don't have to install several versions of the same gem. As I understand you are confused by the dependencies of Chef 11.8.2 of following type:

```
chef-zero >= 1.6.2, ~> 1.6
diff-lcs >= 1.2.4, ~> 1.2
```

In this case you must install the version that supports both constraints. For example for `chef-zero` it will be any version over 1.6.2 (first constraint), but not greater than 2.0 (second constraint). ([Gem dependencies versions meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492772/gem-dependencies-versions-meaning))

It's even easier with json

```
json <= 1.7.7, >= 1.4.4
```

The installed version should be between 1.4.4 and 1.7.7.